# How to make image change for a few seconds when user clicks button and then revert back to original image in swift?

Tags: swift

Hi I am new to coding with Swift and I am also pretty new to Stackoverflow. How do I make a button that changes the image for about 5 seconds and then go back to the original image when the user taps on the button?

I've tried using this code

```
       dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (Int64)(5 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
           gauntletImage.image = UIImage(named: gauntlet["gauntlet2"]) //change back to the old image after 5 sec
       });
```

But I keep getting these 2 errors:

Cannot convert value of type 'Int' to expected argument type 'dispatch_time_t' (aka 'UInt64')

and

Ambiguous use of 'dispatch_get_main_queue()'

This is more of my code that I am using.

```
@IBOutlet weak var gauntletImage: UIImageView!

    let gauntlet = ["gauntlet1", "gauntlet2", "gauntlet3", "gauntlet4", "gauntlet5", "gauntlet6",]


    @IBAction func stonePressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        print(sender.tag)

        gauntletImage.image = UIImage(named: gauntlet[sender.tag - 1]) //change to the new image

        dispatch_after(dispatch_time(dispatch_time_t(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW), (Int64)(5 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            gauntletImage.image = UIImage(named: gauntlet["gauntlet2"]) //change back to the old image after 5 sec
        });
    }
```

Comment: which swift version you use ?

Comment: @Sh_Khan I'm using Swift 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
@IBAction func stonePressed(_ sender: UIButton) { 
    // store old image assuming it has an initial image in storyboard
    let oldImg = gauntletImage.image!
    // set new image
    gauntletImage.image = UIImage(named: gauntlet[sender.tag - 1])  
    // wait 5 seconds 
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 5 ) { 
        // set back old image
        self.gauntletImage.image = oldImg   
   }   

}
```

User may click it multiple times so you may do

```
sender.isEnabled = false
```

when storing the old image and setting it back to `true` inside the dispatch after block